# quantity dropdown box for products

Tags: product, magento-2.1, quantity

How to change the quantity box to dropdown in magento2. I want in dropdown what we add quantity in admin it will show in dropdown up to that value. I mean **if I select quantity option to 4 in admin it shows in fronend drop down with 4 values**.

Comment: Do you have the access to write an extension for this?

Comment: Anyone not a problem@Aravona